# Within a Django Model, how can I prevent a delete based on a particular field?

Tags: django, django-models, overriding, receiver

In the following, I have a `Post` model. A `Post` object has a `status` field that can be `'unpublished'` or `'published'`.

`if status is 'published'`, I'd like to prevent the object from being deleted, and would like to keep this logic encapsulated in the model itself.

```
from model_utils import Choices  # from Django-Model-Utils
from model_utils.fields import StatusField


class Post(model.Models)

    STATUS = Choices(
        ('unpublished', _('Unpublished')),
        ('published', _('Published')),
    )

    ...

    status = StatusField(default=STATUS.unpublished)
```

How can I do this? Overriding the `delete` method won't work if the objects are being deleted in bulk with a `QuerySet`. I've read not to use receivers, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: There is a pre delete event called when you delete via QuerySet.delete(), so listening for it and raising ProtectedError should do the trick.

Comment: I can't find that in the docs - could you point me to this please? I thought that wouldn't send a signal.

Comment: [pre_delete](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/signals/#pre-delete). I'm writing from a phone and can't provide a full answer if you don't get one later I can try to provide one.

Comment: Thanks, I've added an answer based on that

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is what I have following @Todor's comment:

In `signals.py`:

```
from django.db.models import ProtectedError
from django.db.models.signals import pre_delete
from django.dispatch import receiver

from .models import Post

@receiver(pre_delete, sender=Post, dispatch_uid='post_pre_delete_signal')
def protect_posts(sender, instance, using, **kwargs):
    if instance.status is 'unpublished': 
        pass
    else:  # Any other status types I add later will also be protected
        raise ProtectedError('Only unpublished posts can be deleted.')
```

I welcome improvements or better answers!

Comment: Accoring to the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/_modules/django/db/models/deletion/) we have to include the object that is being protected, therefore it should be
raise ProtectedError('Only unpublished posts can be deleted.', instance)

Comment: How do you catch the `ProtectedError`? On my Django 1.11, the exception just bubbles its way to a 500 Server Error.

Comment: @psaniko Have you ever found a way to catch the `ProtectedError`?

Comment: @shadow Don't really remember but I think we had to fix our error handlers or added middleware to catch it. Some SO questions address this directly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44229783/catch-protected-error-and-show-its-message-to-the-user-instead-of-bare-500-code/44231197

Comment: @psaniko Thank you very much for the reply. I got it to work overwriting the delete_view and the response_action as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49326282/