# Django admin not handling ProtectedError exception

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-signals

I have a Django application that has a model like this:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I have a specific instance in this model that it's name is 'bar' (for example) and I want to prevent this instance from being deleted.

I've created a signal receiver like this:

```
def protect_foo_bar(sender, instance, using, **kwargs):
    if instance.title != 'bar':
        pass
    else:
        raise ProtectedError(protected_objects=instance, msg='You cannot delete this object')
```

and I've connected this receiver to `pre_delete` signal like this:

```
pre_delete.connect(receiver=protect_foo_bar, dispatch_uid='protect_foo_bar_signal',
                           sender='app_name.foo')
```

When I try to delete this specific object from Django's admin panel, it returns an exception (Error 500). Is it possible to force the admin panel to show an error like `you cannot delete this object` and not returning an exception to the user?

**EDIT:**

Here's the traceback:

```
Traceback:

File "C:\Users\asus\PycharmProjects\AleTaha\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\asus\PycharmProjects\AleTaha\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\asus\PycharmProjects\AleTaha\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\asus\PycharmProjects\AleTaha\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in wrapper
  551.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\asus\PycharmProjects\AleTaha\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\asus\PycharmProjects\AleTaha\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\asus\PycharmProjects\AleTaha\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py" in inner
  224.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\asus\PycharmProjects\AleTaha\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  67.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\asus\PycharmProjects\AleTaha\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\asus\PycharmProjects\AleTaha\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in bound_func
  63.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "C:\Users\asus\PycharmProjects\AleTaha\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in changelist_view
  1584.                 response = self.response_action(request, queryset=cl.get_queryset(request))

File "C:\Users\asus\PycharmProjects\AleTaha\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in response_action
  1286.             response = func(self, request, queryset)

File "C:\Users\asus\PycharmProjects\AleTaha\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\actions.py" in delete_selected
  49.             queryset.delete()

File "C:\Users\asus\PycharmProjects\AleTaha\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in delete
  614.         deleted, _rows_count = collector.delete()

File "C:\Users\asus\PycharmProjects\AleTaha\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\deletion.py" in delete
  279.                         sender=model, instance=obj, using=self.using

File "C:\Users\asus\PycharmProjects\AleTaha\env\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py" in send
  193.             for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)

File "C:\Users\asus\PycharmProjects\AleTaha\env\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py" in <listcomp>
  193.             for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)

File "C:/Users/asus/PycharmProjects/AleTaha\content\signals.py" in protect_content_category
  8.         raise ProtectedError(protected_objects=instance, msg='دسته‌ی «همه» را نمی‌توان حذف کرد.')

Exception Type: ProtectedError at /admin/content/contentcategory/
Exception Value: ('دسته\u200cی «همه» را نمی\u200cتوان حذف کرد.', <ContentCategory: همه>)
```

Comment: can you share the traceback please?

Comment: @AdamJaamour yes, I've added the traceback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can override the `delete_view()` and `response_action()` methods of your `ModelAdmin`. I would also suggest to override the `has_delete_permission()` method so that the "Delete" button won't appear at all:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def delete_view(self, request, object_id, extra_context=None):
        try:
            return super().delete_view(request, object_id, extra_context)
        except ProtectedError:
            msg = "you cannot delete this object"
            self.message_user(request, msg, messages.ERROR)
            opts = self.model._meta
            return_url = reverse(
                'admin:%s_%s_change' % (opts.app_label, opts.model_name),
                args=(object_id,),
                current_app=self.admin_site.name,
            )
            return HttpResponseRedirect(return_url)

    def response_action(self, request, queryset):
        try:
            return super().response_action(request, queryset)
        except ProtectedError:
            msg = "you cannot delete this object"
            self.message_user(request, msg, messages.ERROR)
            opts = self.model._meta
            return_url = reverse(
                'admin:%s_%s_changelist' % (opts.app_label, opts.model_name),
                current_app=self.admin_site.name,
            )
            return HttpResponseRedirect(return_url)

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None)
        return super().has_delete_permission(request, obj) and (
            not obj or obj.name != 'bar'
        )
```

Comment: thanks, It works when I try to click on the delete button on the object's page. But not when I try to delete multiple objects together. What can I do to handle this exception on deleting multiple objects too?

Comment: I updated my answer overriding `response_action` when I saw your traceback. This should work, doesn't it?

Comment: Oh it works. thank you very much. There is a warning saying `access to a protected member of a class` on `self.model._meta`. Is this ok?

Comment: Yes it's common to access the `_meta` property of a `Model` class, though this is a "protected member". Very useful for model introspection.

Comment: I was searching for how to do this for **days** and finally found your answer. Thank you!