# Creating new Wagtail Hooks

Tags: django, hook, wagtail

there is [list](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/hooks.html) of available Wagtail Hooks.

How do I create my own Hook?

To give you a little context: I want to create a hook which hooks in right before or after an Image/media or a document is deleted. Within the hook I want to validate every page, so there won't be any empty fields/blocks. For some reason it is possible to delete an image and the page will still get served, so in my opinion there should be a function/hook to validate every page again if an image is deleted.

**EDIT:**
On the [Wagtail Roadmap](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/wiki/Roadmap) there is an item about "Object usage reporting - Q3 2021". So for now I just had to think about a work around to fix the error, if a page contained a deleted image and is served.

Answer (score 2):

### Option 1 - Use Signals instead of Hooks

An option could be to leverage the Dango [`Signals`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/signals/) system which are similar to hooks but are more like messages instead of a way to inject content/data.

This does not provide a nice way to present to the user WHY something is blocked but will simply throw an error (you can use a different error type if needed).

This answer is roughly based on a [similar question for generic blocking of deleting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38420603/8070948).

##### `signals.py`

```py
from django.db.models import ProtectedError
from django.db.models.signals import pre_delete
from django.dispatch import receiver

from wagtail.images import get_image_model

image_model = get_image_model()


@receiver(pre_delete, sender=image_model, dispatch_uid='post_pre_delete_signal')
def protect_posts(sender, instance, using, **kwargs):
    # Note: This will block ANY deleting of image models
    # Checking logic can go here
    raise ProtectedError('Only unpublished posts can be deleted.', instance)
```

##### `apps.py`

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'my_app.base'  # must match the configured app name

    def ready(self):
        # signals are imported, so that they are defined and can be used
        import my_app.base.signals ## the import path of the signals file
```

### Option 2 - Override the Images Confirm Delete template

The [Wagtail admin templates can all be overridden](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/advanced_topics/customisation/admin_templates.html), so you could leverage that system to replace the content (or simply append to it) to provide a warning or even block the delete button from showing.

##### `templates/wagtailimages/images/confirm_delete.html`

```html
{% extends "wagtailimages/images/confirm_delete.html" %}


{% block content %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <strong>Warning: Image is also linked to A, B, C</strong>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I gave the signals a try. It is like you said "This does not provide a nice way to present to the user WHY something is blocked". So I did some more research about my Problem and found, that the Roadmap will handle this later this year (see EDIT).  But thanks for the hint with the signals.